# Parse JSON string to Dictionary<String, Integer> with Gson

Tags: java, json, dictionary, gson

I have a JSON string which looks as following: `{"altruism":1,"amazon":6}`

What I want to have is a `HashMap<String, Integer>` with two entries afterwards.

```
Key: altruism Value: 1
Key: amazon Value:6
```

I really can't figure out how to do this. Normally there are objects parsed from JSON strings, but that's not the case here.

Comment: Be clear that JSON is not Gson.  JSON is a data format.  Gson is a Java library for reading and writing JSON.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) makes what you're trying to do relatively easy.  Following is a working example.

```
// input: {"altruism":1,"amazon":6}
String jsonInput = "{\"altruism\":1,\"amazon\":6}";

Map<String, Integer> map = new Gson().fromJson(jsonInput, new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Integer>>() {}.getType());
System.out.println(map); // {altruism=1, amazon=6}
System.out.println(map.getClass()); // class java.util.HashMap
System.out.println(map.keySet().iterator().next().getClass()); // class java.lang.String
System.out.println(map.get("altruism").getClass()); // class java.lang.Integer
```